# Non-continuous Equation Counters (increment per equation type)

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm trying to have two separate equation counters, one for TypeA equations and another of TypeB equations. They shouldn't share a counter, but pick up the counter from whichever type they are within.

Note that this is different than continuous sections, subsections, etc. 
I'm using the `amsmath` package.

I would like the following (I don't care whether its (1.1, 1.2, ...) or (1a, 1b, ...)):

```
TypeA 1 (Funky Equation)
a = n (1.1)
b = m (1.2)

TypeB 1 (Crazy Equation)
a = n (1.1)
b = m (1.2)

TypeA 2 (Funkier Equation)
a = n (2.1)
b = m (2.2)

TypeB 2 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (2.1)
b = m (2.2)

TypeB 3 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (3.1)
b = m (3.2)

TypeB 4 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (4.1)
b = m (4.2)

TypeA 3 (Crazy Equation)
a = n (3.1)
b = m (3.2)
```

I have this in my header:

```
\newtheorem{typeagroup}{TypeA}
\newtheorem{typea}[typeagroup]{TypeA}
\counterwithout{equation}{typeagroup}

\newtheorem{typebgroup}{TypeB}
\newtheorem{typeb}[typebgroup]{TypeB}
\counterwithout{equation}{typebgroup}
```

Notice that the counter is only incremented when a TypeB is present. This is because it's the last `\counterwithin{}` I have in the above definitions.

Here is the format of the code I use for each type of equation:

```
\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{typea}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{typeb}
```

I get the following:

```
TypeA 1 (Funky Equation)
a = n (0.1a)
b = m (0.1b)

TypeB 1 (Crazy Equation)
a = n (1.1a)
b = m (1.1b)

TypeA 2 (Funkier Equation)
a = n (1.1a)
b = m (1.1b)


TypeB 2 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (2.1a)
b = m (2.1b)

TypeB 3 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (3.1a)
b = m (3.1b)

TypeB 2 (Crazies Equation)
a = n (2.1a)
b = m (2.1b)

TypeA 3 (Crazy Equation)
a = n (2.1a)
b = m (2.1b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define new environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{typea*}{Type A}
\newtheorem{typeb*}{Type B}

\newenvironment{typea}
 {\setcounter{equation}{\value{typea*}}\begin{subequations}\begin{typea*}}
 {\end{typea*}\end{subequations}}
\newenvironment{typeb}
 {\setcounter{equation}{\value{typeb*}}\begin{subequations}\begin{typeb*}}
 {\end{typeb*}\end{subequations}}

\begin{document}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\end{document}
```

If you also need “regular” equation numbers independent from these, it can be arranged.

[image]

It's quite simple to add prefixes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{typea*}{Type A}
\newtheorem{typeb*}{Type B}

\newenvironment{typea}
 {\setcounter{equation}{\value{typea*}}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{A-\arabic{equation}}%
  \begin{subequations}%
  \begin{typea*}}
 {\end{typea*}\end{subequations}}
\newenvironment{typeb}
 {\setcounter{equation}{\value{typeb*}}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{B-\arabic{equation}}%
  \begin{subequations}%
  \begin{typeb*}}
 {\end{typeb*}\end{subequations}}

\begin{document}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typeb}[Crazy Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typeb}

\begin{typea}[Funky Equation]
  \begin{align}
      a = n \\
      b = m 
  \end{align}
\end{typea}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, that worked well.  Follow up question: how do I combine phfaist's answer and define a custom counter prefix like A-1a, A-1b; B-1a, B-1b, etc? 
Thanks

Comment: @Student Easy. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that works. Anyway of removing the double alph counter? I'm getting A-1aa, A-1bb.... A2-aa, A-2ab, etc. when all I need is A-1a or A-1.1 Thanks!

Comment: @Student Since I don't get the doubling, I can't tell you how to remove it.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, not sure why I was getting them but incase others do to, I updated your code with a comment, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd like to go via new theorem definitions. You can just define a new counter and alias LaTeX's equation counter to it. Here's my version of a macro `\makeeqcontext` (adapted from some earlier code I had written for myself at some point):

```
\makeatletter
\def\makeeqcontext#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp@eqcontextcountername{eqcounter#1}%
  \expandafter\newcounter{\tmp@eqcontextcountername}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \begingroup%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\c@equation\csname c@eqcounter#1\endcsname%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{#2}%
    %
  }%
  \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{%
    \endgroup%
  }
}%
\makeatother
```

It can be used as follows:

```
\makeeqcontext{<environment-name>}{<equation-label>}
```

and it defines a new environment with the given name in which equations have a separate counter with the given label. Here's a fully working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\makeeqcontext#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp@eqcontextcountername{eqcounter#1}%
  \expandafter\newcounter{\tmp@eqcontextcountername}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \begingroup%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\c@equation\csname c@eqcounter#1\endcsname%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{#2}%
    %
  }%
  \expandafter\def\csname end#1\endcsname{%
    \endgroup%
  }
}%
\makeatother
\makeeqcontext{typea}{A-\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
% default equation type:
\begin{align}
  a = b
  \label{a}
\end{align}
\begin{typea} % equation type A:
  \begin{align}
    c = d
    \label{c}
  \end{align}
\end{typea}
\begin{typea} % equation type A:
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
      e &= f \\
      g &= h \label{g}
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
\end{typea}
Reference~\eqref{a}, \eqref{c} and~\eqref{g}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks [phfaist], that worked well but I did want to define the equation within theorem definitions, etc, hence the usage. I did like the formatting prefixes in the counter like A-1a you used, and asked about it in my comment above. 
Thanks

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't realize you wanted theorems in the first place, I thought that was your approach to solving the problem :)